# Teamcity Deployer plugin broken after server failure

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

After a server failure, the plugin stopped working. I tried (to no avail) removing the folder from .unpacked directory and the .zip file, stopping TC, starting TC, upload plugin again, restart TC.
After that, when I attempt to add any of the plugin build runners is:

> Unexpected Error This was not supposed to happen. Please provide the
>   error details to your TeamCity server maintainer. If you maintain this
>   TeamCity installation please report this error to JetBrains. Error
>   message: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated
>   class file TeamCity: 8.1.2 (build 29993) Operating system: Linux
>   (3.11.10-11-default, amd64) Java: 1.7.0_55-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
>   Servlet container: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 Trace:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated
>   class file at
>   org.apache.jsp.tag.webp.container_tag$Helper.invoke(container_tag.java:365)
>   at
>   org.apache.jsp.tag.webchangeRequest_tag.doTag(webchangeRequest_tag.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.jsp.tag.webp.container_tag._jspx_meth_bs_005fchangeRequest_005f0(container_tag.java:240)
>   at org.apache.jsp.tag.webp.container_tag.doTag(container_tag.java:161)
>   at
>   org.apache.jsp.admin.editRunParams_jsp._jspService(editRunParams_jsp.java:209)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   at
>   jetbrains.spring.web.TeamCityJSPServletImpl.access$001(TeamCityJSPServletImpl.java:7)
>   at
>   jetbrains.spring.web.TeamCityJSPServletImpl$1.apply(TeamCityJSPServletImpl.java:2)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.util.Util.doUnderContextClassLoader(Util.java:68)
>   at
>   jetbrains.spring.web.TeamCityJSPServletImpl.service(TeamCityJSPServletImpl.java:1)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   jetbrains.spring.web.JspController.doHandle(JspController.java:0) at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseController.handleRequestInternal(BaseController.java:75)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>   at

```
... much more that cannot fit here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do add the plugin while TC is not running. Ie. almost same procedure as you described.

- Shutdown TC
- Remove all plugin related files
- Start TC to normal operation
- Shutdown TC completely
- Add the zip file (make sure you dont have any "auto unpack" features and aswell, make sure about filesystem permissions (umask aso.)
- Startup TC.

Any differences??

Could you please describe the "server failure" incident?

Kind regards

Ola Tenglin